# How to format string to get rid of zeros after dot?

Tags: .net, function, formatting

my x is 12.00 nad it is a string. How can I get rid of everything which is after the dot?

It is a fuction and i have to do it by x => x.Something

```
x => x.Format(g);
return this;
```

I've seen that it can be done with Format(g) but it's now working

Comment: If it is a string you can just find the index of the dot (IndexOf) and then keep only the part before the dot index (Substring)

Comment: `Format` formats a non-string value into a string. You can't format a string. You'll have to use string operations to remove the fractional part, eg `Regex.Match(g,@"\d+").Value` or `g[0..g.IndexOf('.')]`, or parse the string into a number and format it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to convert to decimal, then if successfull convert to int:

```
Console.WriteLine("input a number:");
string? x = Console.ReadLine().ToString();
int? n = convert(x);
Console.WriteLine(n);


int? convert(string? x)
{
    decimal d;
    int ? n;
    if (Decimal.TryParse(x, out d))
    {
        n = Decimal.ToInt32(d);        
        return n;
    }
    else
        return null;
}
```